# what is the maximum size of the file in file uploading jQuery?

Tags: jquery, file, size

I am trying to upload files. What is the maximum size of single file I can upload through file upload in jQuery? Is it different to each browser?

Comment: Checking Google:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions
**It is possible to upload files up to 4 GB with the jQuery File Upload plugin.**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922414/file-upload-limit-in-http