# ng-file-upload - file size limit

Tags: amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to upload a large file - 6GB to S3. The S3 file size limit is 15GB. When uploading the 6GB file the request fails with the response null in the error callback. I'm able to successfully upload a 5GB file. Is there a size limit for ng-file-upload? Do I need to use the resumeChunkSize feature, even though this file size is within the limits of S3's 15GB?

```
    return Upload.http({
      url: url,
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: headers,
      data: file,
      resumeChunkSize: '10MB' // necessary?
    })
    .progress(function(evt){
      return evt;
    })
    .error(function errorCallback(response) {
      return response; // null
    })
```

Comment: Are you using a node.js server or express? You may have to configure that to allow a larger request payload. Something like `app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '15gb'}));`

Comment: I'm using node-http-proxy for development and nginx for production. After reading this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922414/file-upload-limit-in-http I think it might be a browser limitation. I checked my backend logs and don't even see the request coming in but not sure if I would because this request is https.