# PHP File Upload Configuration Not Working?

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, configuration, lampp

I am trying to allow file uploads up to 41 Gigabytes. In my php.ini file it says

```
upload_max_filesize = 41G 
post_max_size = 41G
```

I am currently trying to upload a file that according to `ls -l` is 1194328064 bytes which is under 41 Gigabytes. But when I try to upload this file it shows

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 1194328312 bytes exceeds the limit of 41943040 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

What is the problem here? I have already restarted LAMPP.

Comment: 41GB over HTTP? Yikes. I honestly don’t know if that will work on the client side even. Last I heard, 4GB was the high limit, and most people capped it at 2GB for memory reasons. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1922414/231316

Comment: I've seen PHP sites with up to 20GB (https://anonfiles.com for example)

Comment: You probably also need to increase Apache’s limit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691395/231316

Comment: My httpd.conf for Apache currently looks like ```Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    LimitRequestBody 44023414784
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
``` and it is still doing the same thing. Did I edit it incorrectly or is there something else?